# Proof that the set $]a,b[$ is open $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $(\mathbb{R}, T)$ be a topological space induced by the metric $d(x,y)= |x-y|$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.
Show that $]a,b[$ is an open set in $T$, where $a,b \in\mathbb{R}$ and $a<b$.

My attempt:  since $\mathbb{R}\setminus ]a,b[ = ] \infty ,a] \cup [b, \infty[$.
so the complement of $]a,b[$ is closed, Hence $]a,b[$ is open.

I'm just starting to look at topology concepts.

Comment: how is $T$ a topolology? $T$ is a subset of the real line, not a subset of the power set of the real line, which is where the topology should live

Comment: I think it is obviously a typo, and the induced topology by the standard metric is meant.

Comment: Hello :) Why do you know $]-\infty,a]\cup[b,\infty[$ is closed? Commonly, closed sets are defined as the complement of open sets. And open sets $A$ are defined as "There is a small neighborhood $U=\{y\in X\mid d(x,y)<\varepsilon\}$ around every point $x\in A$ with $U\subset A$.

Comment: @Jochen  $]\infty, a] \cup [b, \infty[$  is the union of two closed intervals .

Comment: so how do you know the union of two closed intervals is a closed set? That's no easier to prove than just showing $(a,b)$ is open from the definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

Since a basis of the topology is made up of open balls,  it shouldn't be too hard to find $c\in\mathbf R$ and $r>0$ such that
$$(a,b)=\bigl\{x\in\mathbf R\mid |x-c|<r\bigr\}.$$

Comment: ty so much !!  It's clear now.

Comment: i have a question what  if  we want to proof $(a, \infty )$ is open .

Comment: You could write it is the union of the open intervals $(a+k, a+k+2)$ for all $k\ge 0$.

Comment: I got it !! tnx

Comment: B.y.w., I thought it would look clearer and  more elegant to use the union of all $(a+k-1, a+k+1)$ for $k\ge 1$, so the reader does not ask to himself ‘why 2?’.

Comment: I know why you  put 2 there .

Comment: I guess so.  I was aiming at the average reader.

Comment: Sorry to bother you , I have another question , what's the closure of ]a,b[ . is it [a,b] ?

Comment: You don't bother me. Yes, it's correct. One just adds the limit points that don't belong to $(a,b)$.

Comment: {a} and {b} are the limit points . but how?  Can you explain?

Comment: All neighbourhoods of each contains points in $(a,b)$. Isn't  it clear?

Comment: it's clear !! ty